# How to know when you are in a symbolic link

Tags: python

How to know, in Python, that the directory you are in is inside a symbolic link ?

I have a directory **/tmp/foo/kiwi**

I create a symlink **/tmp/bar** pointing to **/tmp/foo**

I enter into **/tmp/bar/kiwi**

the linux command **pwd** tells me I'm in **/tmp/bar/kiwi**, which is correct.

The python command prompt tells me I'm in **/tmp/foo/kiwi**:

```
Python 2.5.1 (r251:54863, Oct  5 2007, 13:36:32) 
[GCC 4.1.3 20070929 (prerelease) (Ubuntu 4.1.2-16ubuntu2)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.getcwd()
'/tmp/foo/kiwi'
```

Is there a way, in Python, to get the directory I'm really in ?

Comment: Uh, you really are in /tmp/foo/kiwi, not "bar".  /bin/pwd (and os.getcwd()) will report the "physical" location, not the "logical" one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't find anything else, you can use

```
os.getenv("PWD")
```

It's not really a portable python method, but works on POSIX systems. It gets the value of the `PWD` environment variable, which is set by the `cd` command (if you don't use `cd -P`) to the path name you navigated into (see `man cd`) before running the python script. That variable is not altered by python, of course. So if you `os.chdir` somewhere else, that variable will retain its value.

Anyway, as a side node, `/tmp/foo/kiwi` *is* the directory you are in. I'm not sure whether anything apart from the shell knows that you've really navigated through another path into that place, actually :)

Comment: If you do a os.chdir() -- or whatever equivalent Python has, $PWD, inherited from ther environement won't change...

Comment: yeah, it's only for those cases where he has that PWD in his environment and want to get its initial value :)

Comment: So I'll consider it's not really possible in a portable way. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If your symlink is set up in the way you state, then `/tmp/foo/kiwi` is the directory that you're really in. `/tmp/bar/kiwi` is just another way to get to the same place.

Note that the shell command `pwd -P` will give you the physical path of the current directory. In your case, the shell is remembering that you got where you are through the `bar` symlink, so it tell you that you are in `/tmp/bar/kiwi`.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a matter of interest, if you are in a directory you can use the -P option to get the pwd command to resolve all symbolic links to their actual directories.

```
$ ln -s Desktop toto
$ cd toto
$
$ pwd
/home/ken/toto
$ 
$ pwd -P
/home/ken/Desktop
$
```

HTH

cheers,

Rob

Comment: Note that pwd is a builtin in most shells and generally act as "pwd", not "pwd -P". PS: Hi Rob

Answer (score 0):

You could also try lstat.  It will give you info about a file/dir, including telling you whether it's a link and showing you where it links to if it is.

Comment: os.lstat('.') seems to match os.stat('.') when inside a symlinked directory, so probably not of use to the questioner here.

Answer (score 0):

When your shell returning the path, it is relying on the shell enviroment variable "PWD" which gets set as you traverse through the symlink path, but actually it is under the directory as returned by the getcwd(). So, if you get from shell's PWD you will get what you want.

```
>>> os.getcwd()
'/home/ors/foo/tmp/foo/kiwi'
>>> os.environ["PWD"]
'/home/ors/foo/tmp/bar/kiwi'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

```
import os
os.popen('pwd').read().strip('\n')
```

Here is a demonstration in python shell:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.popen('pwd').read().strip('\n')
'/home/projteam/staging/site/proj'
>>> # This returns actual path
>>> import subprocess
>>> p = subprocess.Popen('pwd', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> p.communicate()[0]  # returns non-symlink path
'/home/projteam/staging/deploys/20150114-141114/site/proj\n'
```

Getting the environment variable PWD didn't always work for me so I use the popen method. Cheers!